# Handling multiple push notifications when restarting chrome browser

Tags: push-notification, service-worker

I implemented web push notifications using service worker. Now I am facing an issue. Suppose if I push 5 notifications to an endpoint(chrome browser) and assume the chrome process was not active during the push, then when I start the browser again, it is showing all the queued up notifications at once. How to prevent this scenario?

I tried with getNotifications function. But it is returning me empty notifications array. Following is my code.

```
self.addEventListener('push', function(event) {
 if (!(self.Notification && self.Notification.permission === 'granted')) {
      return;
  }
  var data = event.data.json();
  var options = {
    body: data.notificationText,
    icon: 'files/assets/staff.png',
    vibrate: [100, 50, 100],
    data: {
      dateOfArrival: Date.now(),
      onClickUrl: data.onClickUrl,
      event_id: data.event_id,
      productName: data.product_name
    }
  };

  event.waitUntil(
    self.registration.getNotifications().then(function(notifications) {
      console.log(notifications);
      if (notifications && notifications.length > 0) {
        notifications.forEach(function(notification) {
          notification.close();
        });
      }
      showNotification(data.title, options);
    })
  );
});
```

Comment: How would you like it to behave?

Comment: I would like the notifications to get combined into one notification and push some message like "you have 5 new notifications"

Comment: Check out this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/45973736/1343333

Comment: I tried that, but getNotifications function is returning me an empty array. The code I am using is updated in the question.